# Execute a command on screen termination

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, gnu-screen

I have been using screen for a while, but the process I am running seems to terminate at times, closing the screen out. So I have to reopen the screen again.

I was wondering if it was possible to have a shell script, or just a single instruction executed on screen termination, inorder to reopen the screen automatically unless if I force close it

I love how easy it is to send commands to GNU Screens and i would love to still have that functionality.

edit: In the best case scenario,my screen shouldnt terminate unexpectedly, but if it does. I want to do two things, 1) log time and 2) reopen screen with exact same parameters. but if reopening screen has the screen terminate again. I want to exit out. I would also want to be able to exit out on demand. A shell script would be bad imo, because of nesting of screen, and not enough time to force the upper screen to close, though i could add a sleep timer... anyways this is just a bodged method, I was interested in a better way to achieve this.

Comment: I was thinking if I made a shell script,put my screen command as the first instruction, and called that shell script again within that script in the second, I would achieve something close to what I need.... but I am unsure. Since I am working on a remote server..

Comment: One can create simple shell code that repeats the given command. It could work with or without `screen`, so it's a general approach. But even if a screen-specific solution exists and you would prefer this, I think you should [edit] and add details to the question: should the command be resurrected (1) always? (2) or only if it succeeds? (3) or only if it fails? (4) Including (or excluding) when it's interrupted on demand with Ctrl+C? // The simplest example is like `while true; do your_command; done`. It doesn't rely on `screen` but I believe you can run it inside `screen`.

Comment: sorry for the delay, I edited my original post with additional details....

Comment: I never considered nesting screens. Your problem seems to be with a situation where the process is directly under screen: `screen` – process. The process dies and screen dies. My idea was like: `screen` – script – process. When the process dies, the script can do anything you designed it to do. It can restart the process, write to a logfile, increase count or exit, or whatever. I think the `screen` will notice nothing unless the script exits. And the script exits upon conditions you choose.

Comment: so a bash script, that goes


screen start,


my log statement,


call this script again.


but wont this be nesting multiple scripts if i leave it unattended for months?

Comment: Do not call the script again. Run `screen` with the script *inside* and let the script resurrect the command if needed. You can do this from *another*, outer script if you want to automate the whole process. There is at most one outer script in total, exactly one `screen` in total, exactly one inner script in total, and at most one `your_command` at any given time (but possibly many in total).